# "Cannot call method 'destroy' of undefined" in arrayWillChange

Tags: ember.js

I have what I think is a pretty standard array/template relationship setup, but when I push a new item into the array I get the above mentioned `Cannot call method 'destroy' of undefined` error in the `arrayWillChange` method of the Ember source:

```
for (idx = start + removedCount - 1; idx >= start; idx--) {
  childView = childViews[idx];
  if (removingAll) { childView.removedFromDOM = true; }
  childView.destroy(); <-- childView is undefined
}
```

I have never had this issue before. This doesn't happen when I remove an item from the array. Only on addition. Below is a link for a JSBin where I tried to duplicate the issue. The error doesn't get thrown but the template doesn't update either.

http://jsbin.com/asemul/2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT**:

You're calling `array.push` instead of `array.pushObject` -- the latter is an Ember.js method that is binding aware, which means it will automatically update bindings for you. The handlebars template helper `{{#each filters}}` is a binding to the filters array of the controller, and the template needs to know to update when the underlying array is updated. `push` doesn't tell the binding to update, but `pushObject` does.

Here's a working example (all I did was change push to pushObject): http://jsbin.com/asemul/6/

This is a pretty common mistake -- usually, I find that if my templates aren't synchronized with the underlying object, it's because something's wrong with the bindings, so that's where I start looking.

**END EDIT**

1. I don't think you should be setting `removedFromDOM` directly -- try using `childView.remove()` followed by `destroy()`.
2. I'm not sure what the context is, but have you looked at [`ContainerView`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ContainerView.html) or [`CollectionView`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.CollectionView.html)? Both of those views have support for arrays of child views and may accomplish what you're looking to do both more robustly and with less code.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't specify that the code in my original question is from the Ember source. I didn't call `removedFromDOM` directly. The error that is thrown is from the Ember source. Since what I'm doing is fairly simple, I can't figure out why Ember doesn't like it.

I'll update my question to make it more clear.

Comment: I updated my answer -- you're using ```push``` instead of ```pushObject```. Can you see if using pushObject works?

Comment: That fixed it. I didn't know that was an Ember specific method. I thought it was for pushing JS objects and since I was pushing strings I didn't think I needed that. Good to know, thanks.