# TypeError: Cannot read property 'destroy' of undefined - Ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I use Ember Data 1.0.0-beta.14.1 with Ember 1.9.1 at the moment (with Ember-cli). Somehow one of my collections doesn't work anymore since i update from an older ember data version.

I got a DirectoryModel (for a filesystem). Directories can have subdirectories and files.

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

var DirectoryModel = DS.Model.extend({
    ...

    parent: DS.belongsTo('directory',  { async: true, inverse: 'children' }),

    children: DS.hasMany('directory', { async: true, readOnly: true, inverse: 'parent' }),
    files: DS.hasMany('file', { async: true, readOnly: true })
});
```

A got a serializer to load the hashMany releationships:

```
export default ApplicationSerializer.extend({
    normalizePayload: function(payload) {
        payload.directories.forEach(function(directory) {
            directory.links = {
                children: '/link-to-server'),
                files: 'link-to-server')
            };
        });

        return this._super.apply(this,arguments);
    }
});
```

My view:

```
//WORKS GREAT
{{#each directory in children itemController="file-directory"}}
    ...
{{/each}}

CREATES ERRORS
{{#each file in files }}
     ...
{{/each}}
```

Somehow that files loop ends up to an error. It looks like question ["Cannot call method 'destroy' of undefined" in arrayWillChange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660294/), only in my case I just load the data from the server. I don't understand what i did wrong, as the children-relation does work well. In older versions this just works, but with Ember Data 1.0.0-beta.14.1 it doesn't...

---

I looked at the ember code at the `arrayWillChange` function, and saw that `this._childViews` was just an empty array. But if I set a breakpoint and executed `this.get('content.content').toArray()` in my console, I saw an array with one element. Somehow/somewhere it seems the data is out of sync...

Comment: I've gotten this error recently due to a virtual view naming conflict when inside a component's layout template. However, without more context it's not possible to help you; consider writing a jsbin the reproduces the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end it was a bug in Ember Data 1.0.0-beta.14.1. It's solved in the next version, Ember Data 1.0.0-beta.15: https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/2662

Answer (score 1):

I'm was getting the same error and I also use links to load data. What I accidentally found out is that wrapping arrays in something like

```
files: function() {
  return this.get('directory.files').map(function(file) { return file; });
}.property('directory.files.@each')
```

solves the issue.

Have no idea why it works :)

Comment: Problem was the internal Ember Data function arrayContentDidChange was sometimes incorrectly triggered (see https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/2723). Creating a map probably prevents calling this function at the wrong time. Anyway, problem is fixed with latest Ember Data version.